# Does android tv restricted profiles allow apps to be automatically updated?

Tags: android, android-tv

I just found out the existence of android tv restricted profiles. I've been doing some research and i couldn't find in the documentation if after setting a restricted profile on an adnroid tv device this device will autimatically update all installed apps available for the restricted profile. Could anyone confirm me if this is what happens? If not, does anyone know any tool to update OTA apps on a device with a restricted profile?

I just found Miradore tool but i don't know if this tool works only on mobile devices or also on android tv devices.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It will update the apps specific to the tv, not the user. So if you get an update for one account you will get it for all accounts.

Comment: Ok, so this means that i can set the updates on auto from the google account on the device and then all restricted profiles apps will be updated automatically, am i correct?

Comment: you are correct, at least this is how mine works and it is also an Android TV so I suspect they'll all work the same :)